# internet on iPhone Emulator

Tags: iphone, salesforce

I am a salesforce developer, i need to get a VF page on iPhone device which have been converted to HTML 5 to increases the processing speed of the VF page. So i have download the iPhone Emulator from 
http://downloads.phpnuke.org/en/download-item-view-y-y-m-b-b-a/IPHONE%2BSIMULATOR.htm

But i am not able to get connected to internet. Can anybody help me to solve this problem I am using iPhone Emulator for first time.
Thanks

Comment: what error are you recieving.  What happens wehn you load safari?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may use http://iphone4simulator.com/ or http://transmog.net to test your html5 mobile website